# IOS CSRF-Token Drupal IOS SDK

Tags: ios, drupal, token, csrf

I'm using the Drupal IOS SDK https://github.com/kylebrowning/drupal-ios-sdk 
and now I'm having a problem with CSRF Validation Issue. 
I followed the methods according this URL
https://github.com/kylebrowning/drupal-ios-sdk/wiki/drupal-ios-sdk-2.0

I got no problem with logging in to my Drupal but after logging in, whenever I try to trigger any method such as getting a node method it gives me CSRF Valdation failed 401 as an error instead. I've been searching for the solution over two weeks now. Still got no clue to get rid of it.

If anyone would provide me a solution of this issue, I would be very appreciated.

Thank you very for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally able to get rid of the CSRF validation failed by editing the AFHTTPClient files.
All I need to do is to change the content of the postpath, deletepath, and putpath by using the contents in DIOSCSRFAFHTTPClient instead.